# Vertical Align Issue

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have following styles which work greate but `Vertical-Align:middle` or bottom doesn't work in it. every thing inside goes top ofthe `div`

```
.Progress
{    
display: inline-block;
z-index: 1000;
width:auto;
height: auto;
background-color: #A9C646;
vertical-align: bottom;
text-align: center;
text-align: -moz-center;
!text-align: center;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity = 40);
}
```

Comment: @jarrett - vertical-align doesn't work. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey you can find here css hacks for this issue
[**here**](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-vertical-align.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have height: auto, then the container will be the size of the items it contains, thus is will always appear at the top. Try giving it a defined height.

Comment: I set Height of this element with Javascript

Comment: Can you post a link to this? Have you got anything you can use to debug this to check the height is correct (Firebug in Firefox?)